# impossible to change the input value when using vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I am  new to  vue js  and I have an examination on  it i am  try  to  do the  admin part of a  currency  converter  and  I have to  do an inline table cell  editable  table  that shows all  the  available conventions and  these can  be  modified
here is what i have done but it  don't work correctly  and i am lost

```
<script>

import axios from "../axios_config";
import useValidate from'@vuelidate/core'
import {helpers ,requiredIf ,maxValue}  from '@vuelidate/validators'
import { required, maxLength,minLength,email,oneUpperCase,oneSpecialCharacter,alpha,numeric} from '../lang/i18n-validators'
export default {
    data(){
        return {
              v$:useValidate({
                // $autoDirty:false,
                // $rewardEarly:true,
            $lazy:true,
           
          }),
          
          token_valide:true,
          error_id:null,
          edit_id:null,
          edit_input:null,
          edit_input_id:null,
          currency_exchanges:null,
          focus_triggerer:null,
          focus_out_disable:true,
          updated_inputs:{exchange_rate:null,currency_1:null,currency_2:null},
          fields:[{
            key:'id',
            label:'id',
            editable:false

        },
        {
          key:'currency_1',
          label:'devise 1',
          editable:true
        }
        ,{
          key:'currency_2',
          label:'devise 2',
          editable:true

        },
        {
        key:'consultations',
        label:'consultation',
        editable:false
      },

      { 
        key:'exchange_rate',
        label:'taux de convertion',
        editable:true

      },
     ]
      ,
        

        }
    }
,
    mounted(){

    

    },
   
  
    beforeRouteEnter(route,redirect,next){

        axios.get('/admin/exchange/list')
        .then(function (response) {
          // en cas de réussite de la requête
          console.log(response);
          
          next(vm => {
            vm.currency_exchanges=response.data.data
           
          })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // en cas d’échec de la requête
          console.log(error);
          next(vm => {
            vm.token_valide =false
          })
        })
         
      
  
  
},

validations () {
    return {
      updated_inputs:{
        
          
          currency_1: {
             
              alpha,
              maxLength: maxLength(5)

             
          }
          ,
          currency_2:{
           
            alpha,
            maxLength: maxLength(5)
          
          
          },
          exchange_rate:{

           
            numeric,
            maxValue: maxValue(10000)

          }


        
        
      }
    }
  },
methods:{

  
  value_change($event){
   
    console.log($event)
    const name =$event.target.getAttribute('name');
   
    this.updated_inputs[name]=$event.target.value
    console.log(this.updated_inputs[name])
    
    this.v$.updated_inputs[name].$touch()
    
  },
  input_key_down(e){
    // if(e.code=='tab'){
    //   console.log('tab')
    //   this.focus_out_disable=true
    // }

  },
  input_leave(e){
    
    this.focus_out_disable=false
   
  },
  input_enter(e){
    console.log('enter')
    this.focus_out_disable=true
    

  },
  input_focus(e){
    
    console.log(this.v$)
  },
    input_key(field,currency_exchange){
      return'input_'+currency_exchange.id+'_'+field.key 
    },
  show_edit_input(field,currency_exchange){
   
      return this.edit_id ==currency_exchange.id &&field.editable||this.edit_input==this.input_key(field,currency_exchange)
    

  },
  
  input_blur(e){
   
   
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('blur')
     
    if(this.focus_triggerer=='input' &&this.focus_out_disable==false){
      this.edit_input_id=null
      this.edit_input=null
    }
     if(this.focus_triggerer=='edit_btn' &&this.focus_out_disable==false){
    
      this.edit_id=null
    }

    },150)
  

  },
  table_click(e){
      
        this.focus_out_disable=false

        if(e.target.classList.contains("edit_input")){
          this.focus_out_disable=true;
          return;

        }

        if(e.target.classList.contains("editable_row")){
          this.focus_out_disable=true;
          this.edit_id =null
          this.focus_triggerer='input'
          const parent_row =e.target.closest('tr');
          this.edit_input_id=parent_row.dataset.id
          this.edit_input=e.target.dataset.input_key
          const parent_cell =e.target.closest('td');
        
          
          
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            parent_cell.querySelector('.edit_input').focus()
            
          });
        
          return;
        }

        if(e.target.classList.contains("edit_btn")){
          this.focus_out_disable=true;
          const el = e.target;
         
          const parent =e.target.closest('tr')
          const id =parent.dataset.id
          if(el.dataset.action=='update'){
              this.focus_triggerer='edit_btn'
              this.edit_input =null
              this.edit_input_id =null
           
              this.edit_id=id
              console.log('update')
              this.$nextTick(() => {
                parent.querySelector('td .edit_input_container .edit_input ').focus()
                
              });
          }
          
          if(el.dataset.action=='save'){

             
              console.log('save')
            
    
              
              console.log(this.v$.$errors)
              this.v$.$touch()
             console.log(this.v$)
            
              if(this.v$.$error){
                this.error_id =id
                console.log(this.v$.updated_inputs.exchange_rate.$errors[0].$message)
              
              }
              
             
          }
        
          

        
        
      return;
          
        }
        
      

  }
}
}
</script>

<template >
  
     <div v-if="token_valide==false">
      token expiré
     </div>

    <main v-if="token_valide">
      
        <table @mouseleave="input_leave" :data-headers="this.fields.length + 1" @click="table_click" @keydown="table_key_down" >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
                {{ field.label}} 
              </th>

              <th>
               action
              </th>
            </tr>
          
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            
            <tr v-for="(currency_exchange, index) in currency_exchanges" :key="index" :data-id=currency_exchange.id >
              
              <td v-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">

                       <div class="error" v-if="show_edit_input(field,currency_exchange) && v$.updated_inputs[field.key].$error && v$.updated_inputs[field.key].$dirty && error_id==currency_exchange.id" >  
                    
                      {{ v$.updated_inputs[field.key].$errors[0]?.$message }}
                      </div> 

                <div class="edit_input_container"  v-if="show_edit_input(field,currency_exchange)">

               
                  
                  <input type="text" :name="field.key" @keydown="input_key_down" @input="value_change($event)" @blur="input_blur" class="edit_input" :value="currency_exchange[field.key]">
                </div>
                <div v-else  :class="field.editable?'editable_row':undefined" 
                
:data-input_key="field.editable?input_key(field,currency_exchange):undefined">
                  {{ currency_exchange[field.key]}} 
                </div>
                
              </td>
              
              <td class="action_row" >
                  <div class="btn_container">
                  
                    <button class=" btn edit_btn" tabindex="0" :data-action="edit_id==currency_exchange.id||edit_input_id==currency_exchange.id?'save':'update'">{{
                      edit_id==currency_exchange.id||edit_input_id==currency_exchange.id?'sauvegarder':'modifier'}}</button>

                      <button class=" btn btn_cancel" tabindex="0" v-if="edit_id==currency_exchange.id||edit_input_id==currency_exchange.id">annuler</button>
                  </div>
              
              </td>
            
            </tr>

          </tbody>
          
        </table>

    </main>
</template>

<style scoped>
table{
    width: 90%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
   
}

 th {

 background-color: var(--main_blue);
 color: white;
  
  }
  td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
   
    
    }

  tr:nth-child(even) {

    background-color: #ebe9e9;
    }
    td{
     width: calc(100% / 6);
      max-width: 100px;
    }
    th,td{
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
     }

    input{
      display: inline;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 6px;
      /*border: 0;*/
    }
    #app .btn_container{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
     
    }
    #app .btn{
      height: 60%;
      font-size: 15.5px;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      border: none;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      background-color: hsl(160deg 97.48% 31.1%);
    }

   

    #app .btn_cancel{
      
      margin-left: 8px;
    }

  #app .action_row{
    
    position: relative;
   
  }


#app .editable_row , .edit_input{

  height: 100%;

}

.edit_input{
  
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3cc8e;
  outline-color: #8e8f8f;
}
.edit_input_container {
  height: 100%;
}
#app .editable_row{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
height: 100%;

}


</style>
```

Comment: I don't know if I gave enough detail about my  problem but please help me I'm a student

Comment: It's not enough details in terms of explanation, and also too much code. It's a misunderstanding to believe that any code can be understood by experienced programmers intuitively. There is usually intent and meaning in code only known to the creator. It's incredibly taxing to parse this much code with almost no help or information. It's so much easier if you, as the creator, **explain your code**. It would also be beneficial if you could simplify the code to the **minimum** needed to reproduce the issue, and explain in great detail what it is you're trying to do and the problem you're facing

Comment: Example of what I mean when asking for minimum code: in terms of reproducing and understanding the problem, is the inclusion of any of the classnames or CSS styling necessary?  If not, **remove them from the question**, and anything similarly unnecessary.